# How to run Unity HDRP project on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can'nt build game APK to launch the game. Found error while building APK of game "The platform android is not supported with High Definition".

[image]

Comment: use LWRP or builtin for android

Comment: I think it's not posible to change any project from HDRP to LWRP or LWRP to HDRP.

Answer (score 2):

will you try the change in Build setting => Other settings => Scripting Backend => **Mono**

change  **Mono**  to  **IL2CPP**

then try to build.